# Why It is randomly deleting the nodes while dequeue?

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, circular-list

Here is my code but while dequeue it seems its deleting any random values. Why is it so?
Thank You

```
class Node:        
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
        
class CircularLinkedlist:       
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.size = 0

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            print('List is Empty') 
        else:
            if self.size == 1:
                self.head = None
                self.size -=1
            else:
                pos = self.head.next
                self.head = pos
                self.head.next = pos.next.next
                self.size -=1
```

Comment: Why do you think it's deleting random nodes?

Comment: `self.head.next = pos.next.next` is wrong. You're linking the first node to the third node for some reason (cutting out the second node).

Comment: What is `self.head.next = pos.next.next` supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
self.head.next = pos.next.next
```

is wrong. You're linking what is now the first node to the third node (cutting out the second node).

I don't see any reason for that line: I suggest you delete it.